# How do I import a Google sheet in a chrome extension project?

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome-extension

I wish to enhance an existing web page by adding statistics that can be regularly fed by a large amount of people.

I chose to use Google Sheets to retrieve the data so that anyone can access the tables and make their addition but I have no clue of how to display the sheet's results in the concerned web page.

In my case, I'm editing the webpage's text from Javascript.
I thougth of two tools that might help:

1. Importing the google sheet in Javascript (I can't find how to do that, an alternative would be welcome if not possible)
2. Importing the google sheet in Python and then exporting its results as an internal .txt file which I should be able to read with Javascript but that would require the .txt file to be updated every now and then.

Could you guys lend me a hand in how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can publish a google sheet as a web page and it updates like every 5 minutes with changes?

Comment: Can you show what you have already attempted to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.